# Azure Development Tools in Mac Visual Studio

Tags: azure, macos, visual-studio

I have moved to utilizing the Mac version of Visual Studio. I need to work on Azure Functions. In the Windows environment, I would go under tools and install the Azure Development Tool to be able to work with Azure Functions. I cannot locate that on the Mac version. Is it not there yet? Can I install it via CLI?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/mac/azure-functions?view=vsmac-2022

Comment: Is there a way to add it to an existing project or does it have to be separate on the Mac version?